# How to test file downloads in Capybara using Selenium?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, rspec, capybara

I want to test that a file is able to be downloaded using RSpec and Capybara with Selenium as the driver. How should I click the accept download modal option and then test that the file downloaded had the right content?

Comment: Dup:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29309324/how-to-test-csv-file-download-in-capybara-and-rspec